# Separate controllers for singular and listing?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Say I have a user type of 'Teacher', and I have a listing page that shows all 'Teachers'. How would be best to do this? I have the following:

```
$teachers = new Teachers;
$data = $teachers->getTeachers();

foreach($data as $teacher) {
    echo $teacher->name
}
```

and my singular page would be:

```
$teacher = new Teacher('Jane Doe');
echo $teacher->name;
```

**Compared to:**

```
$teachers = new Teachers;

$all = $teachers->getTeachers();

foreach($all as $teacher) {
    echo $teacher->name;
}
```

and my singular being:

```
$teacher = $teachers->getTeacher('Jane Doe');
echo $teacher->name;
```

Essentially, should I have a separate controller/model for the listing and singular, or incorporate them into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a model called `Teacher` which can be used to get all or a single teacher from db. Of course the model is responsible to create/update/delete teachers as well.

```
class Teacher { // this should extend a Model class which share common methods to all models

  public $id;
  public $name;

  public function __construct($id, $name)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public static function find($id) // this is a common method
  {
    // query db to get the teacher with given ID
    // The results are assigned to $row variable

    return self::createFromArray($row);
  }

  public static function all()
  {
    // query db to get all the teachers

    $teachers = []; // instead of an array you can create a collection class which may have some useful methods

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $teachers[] = self::createFromArray($row);
    }

    return $teachers;
  }

  public static function get($attributes)
  {
    // you can build a query with where clause by given attributes (eg. if you want to search by name)
    // after getting the results you can use the same example as all() method
  }

  public static function createFromArray($fields) // this is a common method
  {
    return new self(...$fields); // ... operator since PHP 5.6
  }
}
```

In your controller you can use the model like:

```
foreach (Teacher::all() as $teacher) {
    echo $teacher->name;
}
```

or

```
echo Teacher::find(1)->name; // echo the name of the teacher having ID 1
```

or

```
foreach (Teacher::get(['name' => 'John']) as $teacher) {
   echo $teacher->name;
}
```

This example was inspired from Laravel. You can see how the models are used in Laravel to understand more about this concept.

I just gave you a minimal example on how to create and use a model but you can try more things around this idea.

Comment: Thanks, with our system its slightly different to your standard MVC pattern. We have a backend 'Model' and a front end 'controller' for our custom cms. 

This has cleared it up though :)